# How to print elements in Python linked list alternatively left and right from middle?

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have **linked list** in Python like this

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, dataval=None):
        self.dataval = dataval
        self.nextval = None

class SInglylInkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.headval = None

lst = SInglylInkedList()
lst.headval = Node("Jan")
e2 = Node("Feb")
e3 = Node("Mar")
e4 = Node("Apr")
e5 = Node("May")
e6 = Node("June")
e7 = Node("July")
e8 = Node("Aug")
e9 = Node("Sep")
e10 = Node("Oct")
e11 = Node("Nov")
e12 = Node("Dec")

lst.headval.nextval = e2

e2.nextval = e3
e3.nextval = e4
e4.nextval = e5
e5.nextval = e6
e6.nextval = e7
e7.nextval = e8
e8.nextval = e9
e9.nextval = e10
e10.nextval = e11
e11.nextval = e12
```

Now this method will print elements in straight order

```py
def listprint(self):
    printval = self.headval
    while printval is not None:
        print (printval.dataval)
        printval = printval.nextval
```

> Jan **→** Feb **→** Mar **→** Apr **→** May **→** June **→** July
>   **→** Aug **→** Sep **→** Oct **→** Nov **→** Dec

I want to print element **alternatively left and right from the middle** like this

> June **→** July **→** May **→** Aug **→** Apr **→** Sep **→** Mar
>   **→** Oct **→** Feb **→** Nov **→** Jan **→** Dec

**Help me with writing the print method**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took some liberties and reimplemented the SinglyLinkedList class, but the idea is the same. To generate the alternating pattern - as you iterate over your nodes - you can use a stack to keep track of nodes up until the middle of your original linked list. Once you're at the middle, you no longer push nodes onto the stack, and you only pop from the stack and append to your new linked list, while also appending the current node you're looking at.

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

class SinglyLinkedListIterator:

    def __init__(self, node):
        self.node = node

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.node is None:
            raise StopIteration
        node, self.node = self.node, self.node.right
        return node

class SinglyLinkedList:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = self.head
        self.length = 0

    def __len__(self):
        return self.length

    def __iter__(self):
        return SinglyLinkedListIterator(self.head)

    def append(self, *values):
        for value in values:
            node = Node(value)
            if self.head is None:
                self.head = node
            else:
                self.tail.right = node
            self.length += 1
            self.tail = node

    def display(self):
        for node in iter(self):
            print(node.value, end=[" -> ", "\n"][node is self.tail])

    @staticmethod
    def to_alternate(linked_list):
        linked_list_alt = SinglyLinkedList()
        node_stack = []
        length = len(linked_list)
        for index, node in enumerate(linked_list):
            if index <= (length // 2) - [1, 0][length%2]:
                node_stack.append(node)
            else:
                linked_list_alt.append(node_stack.pop().value)
                linked_list_alt.append(node.value)
        while node_stack:
            linked_list_alt.append(node_stack.pop().value)
        return linked_list_alt

def main():

    linked_list = SinglyLinkedList()

    months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
    linked_list.append(*months)
    linked_list.display()

    SinglyLinkedList.to_alternate(linked_list).display()

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
Jan -> Feb -> Mar -> Apr -> May -> June -> July -> Aug -> Sep -> Oct -> Nov -> Dec
June -> July -> May -> Aug -> Apr -> Sep -> Mar -> Oct -> Feb -> Nov -> Jan -> Dec
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you show no code of your own on the problem, I'll just give a few ideas for an algorithm. (You show code to set up a linked list and to print it as usual but no code attempt for the actual problem.) If you me to show you some code, first do some more work and show it in your question.

One solution is to convert the linked list to a standard Python `list`. You then find the length of this list then generate the desired indices, accessing the values associated with those indices. In your particular example, the length of the list is `12`, so you generate these indices in this order:

```
5, 6, 4, 7, 3, 8, 2, 9, 1, 10, 0, 11
```

I hope you see the pattern(s) there.

Another way that avoids a standard list is to build a reversed linked list. You don't need to reverse the entire linked list, just the first half. In those indices I generated above, you can see the sub-list `5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0`, which is the first half of the list in reverse. You can build that list, then use that reversed first-half and the second half of your original list in alternation to do the printing.

But that way may still use memory to copy half your list. You could avoid that memory by using a stack or recursion to just access the first half of your list in reverse order. This still uses memory, but just for pointers to your list items. (I mean pointers in memory at the base level--Python hides the actual pointers.)

If you want more detail, show some more of your own work and I will be glad to explain more in words and in code.

Answer (score 1):

I think in your question you meant to write

`lst.headval.nextval = e2 instead of lst.headval.nextval = e12`, correct?

A quick and dirty solution is

```
def listprint_answer(self):
    topval = self
    bottomval = self.nextval
    while bottomval.nextval is not None:
       newtopval=lst.headval
       while newtopval.nextval is not topval:
           newtopval=newtopval.nextval
       print(topval.dataval)
       topval=newtopval
       print(bottomval.dataval)
       bottomval=bottomval.nextval
    print(lst.headval.dataval)
    print(bottomval.dataval)
listprint_answer(e6)
```